# Vue.js updating content of an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array `feedListBox` which i assigned to my feeds object of data. When i update feedListBox array, Vue.js does not detect it. Therefore i use `fixFeedArray` method in the script.js file `myApp.fixFeedArray()`. It works really fine, but i wonder if there is another way to do it without using any function in the script file. I mean automatically.

```
var myApp = new Vue({
    el: '#my-App',
    data: {
        feeds: feedListBox,
    },
    methods: {
        fixFeedArray: function fixFeedArray() {
            this.feeds = feedListBox;
        }
   }    
});
```

Here is the function which changes the value of feedListBox array in the script file

```
 function searchByCategory() {
        var category = $("#categoryBox").val();
        var searchedCategories = feedArray.filter(function (item) {
            return item.category.includes(category);
        });
        feedListBox = searchedCategories;

        myApp.fixFeedArray();
    }
```

Comment: can you make a demo where `feedListBox` changes its value ?

Comment: @user2486 I have added the function which changes the value of feedListBox arry.

Comment: Why `searchByCategory` is not in vue ?

Comment: @user2486 I don't know, should it be?

Comment: If there is no specific reason yes it should be in vue . And you can use computed method. Try for this first , if you unable I will post as I am suggesting

Comment: @user2486 Thus you mean that i should put the content of searchByCategory function to an computed method?

Comment: Yes and set `feeds` there

Comment: @user2486 Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would personally ditch jQuery. Here's a quick example of how I would push new data into an Array for Vue to react to it and re-render. If it's not a utility function I would advise keeping all functions that manipulate data into the methods object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: {
    error: null,
    newText: '',
    newValue: '',
    categories: [{
        text: "Shapes",
        value: "shapes"
      },
      {
        text: "Colors",
        value: "colors"
      },
      {
        text: "Sizes",
        value: "sizes"
      },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      if (this.newText === '' ||
        this.newValue === '') {
        return this.error = 'Please fill out the form!'
      }
      this.categories.push({
        text: this.newText,
        value: this.newValue,
      });
      return this.clear();
    },
    clear: function() {
      this.newText = '';
      this.newValue = '';
      this.error = '';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  {{ error }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in categories">
      {{ item.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <label>Text</label>
  <input v-model="newText" type="text" />
  <label>Value</label>
  <input v-model="newValue" type="text" />
  <button v-on:click="test">Add to Array</button>
</div>
```